# Does Spring Insight no longer exists

Tags: tcserver, spring-insight

I've downloaded a few versions of STS and the latest tcServer developer edition.  None of these packages have the Insight template available.

The instructions on how to create a tcServer to do this spring profiling is dead simple.  It just doesn't work.  So the simple question is has this feature been removed from tcServer?

In the unlikely event the answer is "No", then every web page and PDF on the Internet is wrong.  So the follow-on question is "How would one go about creating this server?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 3.2.x, the template is not included, but can be installed on-demand by using the tcruntime-admin get-template command.

http://tcserver.docs.pivotal.io/docs-tcserver/topics/template.html#managing-templates

Let me know if you have any other questions.

-Jason

Comment: Just WOW!  There's 2 days I'd like to have back!  Thanks Jason.